# Knapsack 0-1 in R

Tags: r, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I have been trying to formulate a simple knapsack problem, but I cannot see why it is not working.

```
i <- c(1,2,3,4)
v <- c(100,80,10,120)
w <- c(10,5,10,4)
k <- 15

F <- function(i,k){
  if (i==0 | k==0){
    output <- 0
  } else if (k<w[i]){
    output <- F(i-1,w)
  } else {
    output <- max(v[i]+ F(i-1, k-w[i]), F(i-1,k))
  }
  return(output)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having a look at the `knapsack` function of the package adagio should help you, where `w` is the vector of weights, `p` the vector of profits and `cap` is your `k`. (see `?knapsack`)

```
knapsack <- function (w, p, cap) {
    n <- length(w)
    x <- logical(n)
    F <- matrix(0, nrow = cap + 1, ncol = n)
    G <- matrix(0, nrow = cap + 1, ncol = 1)
    for (k in 1:n) {
        F[, k] <- G
        H <- c(numeric(w[k]), G[1:(cap + 1 - w[k]), 1] + p[k])
        G <- pmax(G, H)
    }
    fmax <- G[cap + 1, 1]
    f <- fmax
    j <- cap + 1
    for (k in n:1) {
        if (F[j, k] < f) {
            x[k] <- TRUE
            j <- j - w[k]
            f <- F[j, k]
        }
    }
    inds <- which(x)
    wght <- sum(w[inds])
    prof <- sum(p[inds])
    return(list(capacity = wght, profit = prof, indices = inds))
}
```

However, the problems in your function seem to be

1. You did not declare all the objects used in your function (`w` and `v`) : you should also declare them as parameters of your function.
2. `F` which is the name of your function is called inside your function. Hence, as `(i==0 | k==0)` could never be true, the function will never stop processing.